# How to delete element from a Map based on property of value object

Tags: javascript, object

```
myMap.set(id, {x: 10, y: 20})
myMap.delete(id)
```

How can I delete element from a Map based on property of value object? for example in above code instead of deleting based on key, delete based on `x` from value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the map's `entries` and find the one with the value you want, then delete the associated key from the map:

```js
const map = new Map();
const id = 'foo';
map.set(id, {x: 10, y: 20});
console.log(map.size);

const foundIdEntry = [...map.entries()]
  .find(([, { x }]) => x === 10);
if (foundIdEntry) map.delete(foundIdEntry[0]);

console.log(map.size);
```

That said, if you're having to do something like this regularly, it would probably be a lot better to reconsider your data structure - you might want a `Map` whose keys are the `x` values, rather than whose keys are the IDs:

```
map.set(10, { id: 'foo', y: 20 });
```

Or, when setting a value to the map, also set a key-value pair in a separate object that maps `x`s to its associated `id`, so that you can access it in the future with plain property lookup, rather than `.find`:

```
const idsByX = {};
map.set(id, {x: 10, y: 20});
idsByX['10'] = id;
```

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the explanation

Comment: one question: can a map have elements with same keys? if yes: and so if I do `map.delete(key)` it will delete all the elements with same key?